# Problems with video length when join video file using ffmpeg concat

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have 3 videos:

- `open.avi` – 0:46:37.885933 duration
- `middle.avi` – 0:02:56.991927 duration
- `fin.avi` – 0:02:48.199268 duration

I try to concat 3 videos using command:

```
$ ffmpeg -i "concat:fin.avi|open.avi|middle.avi" -preset ultrafast -c copy -y vide.avi

ffmpeg version 1.2.4 Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Oct 16 2013 22:38:01 with gcc 4.8.1 (GCC) 20130603 (Red Hat 4.8.1-1)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --bindir=/usr/bin --datadir=/usr/share/ffmpeg --incdir=/usr/include/ffmpeg --libdir=/usr/lib --mandir=/usr/share/man --arch=i686 --optflags='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m32 -march=i686 -mtune=atom -fasynchronous-unwind-tables' --enable-bzlib --disable-crystalhd --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-libass --enable-libcelt --enable-libdc1394 --disable-indev=jack --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-openal --enable-libopencv --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-x11grab --enable-avfilter --enable-avresample --enable-postproc --enable-pthreads --disable-static --enable-shared --enable-gpl --disable-debug --disable-stripping --shlibdir=/usr/lib --cpu=i686 --enable-runtime-cpudetect
  libavutil      52. 18.100 / 52. 18.100
  libavcodec     54. 92.100 / 54. 92.100
  libavformat    54. 63.104 / 54. 63.104
  libavdevice    54.  3.103 / 54.  3.103
  libavfilter     3. 42.103 /  3. 42.103
  libswscale      2.  2.100 /  2.  2.100
  libswresample   0. 17.102 /  0. 17.102
  libpostproc    52.  2.100 / 52.  2.100
Input #0, avi, from 'concat:fin.avi|open.avi|middle.avi':
  Duration: 00:02:48.20, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 28159 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg (MJPG / 0x47504A4D), yuvj422p, 640x480, 11.20 tbr, 11.20 tbn, 11.20 tbc
Output #0, avi, to 'vide.avi':
  Metadata:
    ISFT            : Lavf54.63.104
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg (MJPG / 0x47504A4D), yuvj422p, 640x480, q=2-31, 11.20 tbn, 11.20 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=27988 fps=2386 q=-1.0 Lsize=  578159kB time=00:41:38.70 bitrate=1895.5kbits/s    
video:577498kB audio:0kB subtitle:0 global headers:0kB muxing overhead 0.114549%
```

When I change the order of input video:

```
    Input #0, avi, from 'concat:open.avi|middle.avi|fin.avi':
  Duration: 00:46:37.89, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1692 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg (MJPG / 0x47504A4D), yuvj422p, 640x480, 8.61 tbr, 8.61 tbn, 8.61 tbc
Output #0, avi, to 'vide.avi':
  Metadata:
    ISFT            : Lavf54.63.104
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg (MJPG / 0x47504A4D), yuvj422p, 640x480, q=2-31, 8.61 tbn, 8.61 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=27988 fps=2343 q=-1.0 Lsize=  578159kB time=00:54:11.01 bitrate=1456.9kbits/s    
video:577498kB audio:0kB subtitle:0 global headers:0kB muxing overhead 0.114549%
```

What can I do to fix it?

Comment: I think it is taking the frame rate of the first input. One shows 2386 and the other 2343. You **could** explicitly state a framerate and try. But maybe Setpts should also be used.

Comment: I try to using concat filter to fix it!!!

Comment: And does it work with the filter?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it with re-running `ffmpeg` on concatenation output using copy streams option. So, with your file names it would be:

```
ffmpeg -i vide.avi -c copy vide_fixed.avi
```

I didn't test it with avi though. It was mp4 in my case.